# size of ICMP type 11 packet payload

Tags: size, ip, packet, icmp, payload

What's the size of the ICMP packet payload when the type is 11, i.e. time exceeded? 
Since it contains an IP header and the first 8 Bytes of the IP packet payload generating the ICMP message, I thought its size was 20 + 8 = 28.

I'm replaying some common user traffic with TTL=1. In the ICMP messages I have dumped I noticed that:

- all ICMP packets generated by UDP packets have payload of size 28 Bytes
- all those generated by TCP packets have payload of size 40 Bytes

Since I need to match ICMP time-exceeded messages with the packets that triggered them by comparing those bytes, this piece of information is essential, but I can't find figure out why this happens.

Comment: Deleted my answer because I didn't realise you were sending a time exceeded package. You might want to add some information about how you're generating the message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're quoting the 8-byte header payload from [RFC 792, Page 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792), but the requirements were  changed by RFC 1812...

```
Time Exceeded Message (in RFC 792)

    0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |     Type      |     Code      |          Checksum             |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                             unused                            |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |      Internet Header + 64 bits of Original Data Datagram      |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

[RFC 1812, Section 4.3.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1812#section-4.3.2.3) dramatically increases the allowable payload in an ICMP Error message (emphasis mine):

> **4.3.2.3 Original Message Header**
>
> Historically, every ICMP error message has included the Internet
> header and at least the first 8 data bytes of the datagram that
> triggered the error.  This is no longer adequate, due to the use of
> IP-in-IP tunneling and other technologies.  *Therefore, the ICMP
> datagram SHOULD contain as much of the original datagram as possible
> without the length of the ICMP datagram exceeding 576 bytes*.  The
> returned IP header (and user data) MUST be identical to that which
> was received, except that the router is not required to undo any
> modifications to the IP header that are normally performed in
> forwarding that were performed before the error was detected (e.g.,
> decrementing the TTL, or updating options).

The ICMP Errors you're generating from Scapy packets should contain all the information from the IP and TCP layers of the original packet.

Comment: Thank you. I "manually" matched data packets and their time-exceeded ICMP messages, only to find out that I was getting one match for each TCP packet if the ICMP payload considered was 28B long and when I considered more than 28B, I hardly ever got a match. I really think it has something to do with the library I'm using to inspect packets (Scapy). I wrote something more in answer to stuart's reply.

Comment: I am curious, is responding to the one-byte payload difference part of the bounty award, or was the reference for the payload size sufficient?

Comment: If you could help with that thing too, it'd be great. Otherwise, no worries!

Comment: Recently I found out about ICMP extensions for MPLS. http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-mpls-icmp-01 It reminded me of this question of mine ;)

Comment: fyi, draft-ietf-mpls-icmp-01 is most recently updated as [rfc 4950](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4950)... not yet approved though

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, the ICMP payload is the IP header plus 8 octets of the original packet's payload. IP headers, however, are not always 20 octets long; 20 is only the minimum. The IP header itself may contain options, and the header length is indicated by the value in the IHL field of the header. See sec 3.1 of RFC 791. So it looks like the TCP packets have 12 additional octets of options in their IP headers. RFC 791 defines some standard options such as source routing and timestamping. You'll have to decode the header to determine what options are being used.

Comment: I digged a bit more into the problem and according to Scapy, the tool with which I'm sending and forging my packets, the IP header is always 20B in size. I had a look at those 20 Bytes of TCP header and it looks like Scapy is padding some additional bytes into them each time, because the last extra bytes differ only in like 1 byte, all the other ones being always the same.    Not sure why this happens... it still baffles me.

Comment: While that was the case at the time I wrote the comment, now I'm finally getting ICMP payloads larger than 28 Bytes. Dreams come true...

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add for future reference that not only do ICMP payloads vary in size as Mike said, they might also be longer than **128 Bytes** in the case of **ICMP extensions for MPLS**. See [this draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-mpls-icmp-01) for more information